# Powershell variable value to elasticsearch cluster

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch

I want to index data from PowerShell into Elasticsearch. 
The data from the variable: 
`$var1=Get-Process|Select-Object CPU | ConvertTo-Json`

$var1 output:

```
[
   {
       "CPU":  11.265625
   },
   {
       "CPU":  0.09375
   },
   {
       "CPU":  13.796875
   },
   {
       "CPU":  0.109375
   },
   {
       "CPU":  0.953125
   },
   {
       "CPU":  624.65625
   },
   {
       "CPU":  3.96875
   },
   {
       "CPU":  0.046875
   },
   {
       "CPU":  1.15625
   },
   {
       "CPU":  0.125
   },
   {
       "CPU":  0.625
   },
   {
       "CPU":  0.65625
   },
   {
       "CPU":  0.109375
   }
]
```

I am attempting to load data with a command:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -ContentType 'application/json' -Method POST `
                  -Uri 'http://localhost:9200/123456789/doc' `
                  -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($var1)) -UseBasicParsing
```

or

```
 Invoke-WebRequest -ContentType 'application/json' -Method POST `
              -Uri 'http://localhost:9200:9200/123456789/doc' `
              -Body $var1 -UseBasicParsing
```

I get the error message:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"not_x_content_exception: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent
bytes"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"not_x_content_exception: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent
bytes"}},"status":400}
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -ContentType 'application/json' -Method POST `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Does anyone know how to make it work within the PowerShell environment?

My Powershell version is:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      15063  1387
```

I believe it might be related to the JSON syntax.

Comment: In your first uri (http://localhost:9200/123456789/doc) youbtry to create a document with the type "doc" located in the index identified by "123456789". Is this index present?

Comment: In the second uri, you've doubled the port (http://localhost:9200:9200/123456789/doc). Thats not how it works.

Comment: Your document in your var1 is a array of documents - right? If you want to index multiple docs at once, please use the bulk api